# javascript callback - how to use call backs

Tags: javascript, callback

I need help with this JS callback function. I am trying to figure out how exactly callbacks work in JS.

--quick test code follows:

```
function debFilter(deb_array, fillCb){
    var filt_darr = [];
    for (var inx in deb_array) {
        filt_darr.push(fillCb(deb_array[inx]));
    }

  return filt_darr;

}
console.log(debFilter(savedInp, function(x) { if (x%2 == 0) { return x;}} ));
```

Let's say my savedInp array contains [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] something like this. How do I make sure my callback returns only the even elements and not the odd ones? so my filt_darr would be [2,4,6...etc].
With the above test code I am getting [2,undefined,4,undefined,..etc]. I have tried with other similar conditions too with no avail. I just need to know how to tell JS not to 'push/return' something I dont need. Sorry if this is a beginner Q.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array and then push evens into a new array:

```
 var a = [1,2,3,4,5];

 function getEvens(originalArray){

  var evens = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; ++i){
     if(originalArray[i] % 2 === 0){
        evens.push(originalArray[i]);
     }
   }

   return evens;
 }
```

Comment: thanks but not what I am asking. I know how to do filtering with simple techniques :)

Answer (score 0):

As you probably noticed, you are collecting every return value into your result array and your callback returns `undefined` for every odd.
You could change your code to sth like

```
function debFilter(deb_array, fillCb){
        'use strict';

        var filt_darr = [],
            len = deb_array.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (fillCb(deb_array[i])) {
                  filt_darr.push(deb_array[i]);
            }
        }

        return filt_darr;
    }
```

By the way, ES 5 supports [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which might be what you are looking for. There is also a polyfill that you can take some inspiration from.